# I installed Ubuntu with Windows installer, now I only have an NTFS partition. Why?

Tags: partitioning

I am trying to give Ubuntu a bigger partition, but when I run Partition Magic, it only show the NTFS partition taking up the entire drive.  Where is Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

wubi installs into a file (root.disk)  that is then loop mounted.

A standard installation modifies your partitions.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide , search that page for virtual disk. It is not well explained, perhaps see also loop mount - http://samindaw.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/mounting-a-file-as-a-file-system-in-linux/

> Mounting a file as a file system in Linux
>
> This is called mounting a loopback device.
>   3 steps.
>
> Creating the file that can be mounted as a file system
>      Assigning the file as a block device
>      Mounting the block device to a path

...